# Close a dialog in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calendar in my page which have a `more info` button.

That button opens when clicked upon but do not close.

How can i close it?

Button:

```
$('a.cmoreinf').live('click', function() {
    $('.ccontent').each(function() {
        $(this).css('display','none');
    });
    $(this).closest('.calsingleentry').find('.ccontent').css('display','block');
    return false;
});
```

[Calendar Page](http://tranceil.fm/?page_id=43)

Comment: as a side note `live` is deprecated on latest jQuery versions. Use `on()` instead

Comment: Maybe all `.ccontent` elements are affected by `.css('display','block')`, so you would not see a difference (i.e. `.css('display','none')` won't have any effect)? Impossible to tell without seeing the HTML or a demo.

Comment: the page is -> http://tranceil.fm/?page_id=43

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all the information needed to really answer this question but I believe you're wanting to have a modal appear on the first click, disappear on the second, appear on the third etc... basically toggling the display property. If so...

```
$('a.cmoreinf').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.ccontent').hide();
  $(this).closest('.calsingleentry').find('.ccontent').toggle();
});
```

[jQuery toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: i added the page link in my question...i tried your code but when using it the click brings the page to top, opens the dialog but not close

Answer (score 1):

The class `ccontent` is inside the div `calsingleentry`.

Use this:

```
$('a.cmoreinf').live('click', function() {
    $('calsingleentry').find('.ccontent').each(function() {
        $(this).css('display','none');
    });
    $(this).closest('.calsingleentry').find('.ccontent').css('display','block');
    return false;
});
```